# Python scraping returns none

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to take a name from a HTML page with BeautifulSoup:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

nightbot = 'https://nightbot.tv/t/tonyxzero/song_requests'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(nightbot)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')

list_item = soup.find('strong', attrs={'class': 'ng-binding'})
print (list_item)
```

But when i print `print(list_item)` i get a `none` as reply. There is a way to fix it?

Comment: try print(soup.prettify()) and see if the tag you think should be there is actually there.

Comment: The tag isn't there. Using Maaz's solution worked. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpage is rendered by javascript. So you have to use a package like `selenium` to get what you  want.

You can try this:

**CODE:**

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://nightbot.tv/t/tonyxzero/song_requests')

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

list_item = soup.find('strong', attrs={'class': 'ng-binding'})
print (list_item)
```

**RESULT:**

```
<strong class="ng-binding" ng-bind="$state.current.title">Song Requests: TONYXZERO</strong>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Now my only problem is making him get the right ng-binding

Comment: If you know where is your targeted tag, you can use `find_all()` method instead of `find()` which return a list and then pick the right tag inside. Or you have to find another way to select it (another attribute...)